# objective c - set relationship (core data)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, relationship

I'm very new to `core data` and the project that I'm currently working on involves using core data for local data storage.

Below is the structure of my entities.

[image: Entities]

My app functions as follows. When the user first launches the app, there are presented with a login screen. New users can register. When a user tries to register, they have to enter a unique key that has already been provided to them, prior to the registration. This unique key is validated in the `Facility` table. If the key exists, in the db, then I will enter the user data into the database and will create a relationship between the `Assessor` and the `Facility`that they just entered the code for.

My question is, how would I create a relationship between a new `Assessor` and an existing `Facility`?

I'm thinking, I should fetch the required `Facility` object from `core data` and then use `[assessor`setValue:facilityObject`forKey:@"facility"]` to set the object.

Can anyone help me understand how to fetch the `facilityObject` from the `Facility` table in `core data` before assigning it to the `Assessor`?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
For example:

This is how my `Facility` table will look like.

### code  |  name

H6DJ  | Computing

So if the user (John Doe) enters H6DJ as the registration code, I check the Facility table to see if it exists. so in this case, I would like to create a relationship between the new user (John Doe) and the Computing facility.

Comment: that is why always use SQLLite... its most easiest to use.. core data is easy if its normal database, but complex makes it worst...

Comment: This depends on what you really want to do. Show all Facilities in a table? Get the Facility that matches a `code` or `name`? Have you used `NSFetchRequest` before?

Comment: @FahimParkar, it's too late to change now.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch, I'll edit my post to add an example. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html) provides lots of sample code.

Your idea about setting the `facility` property of the new assessor entity is correct - you just need to fetch the facility first - presumably you would need to do this anyway to validate the facility code that was entered.

```
NSManagedObject *newAssessor = [NSEntityDescription
insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Assessor"
inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity =
[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Facility"
        inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate =
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"code == %@", targetCode];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error;
NSArray *array = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (array != nil) {
    NSUInteger count = array.count; 
    if (count == 1) { 
        NSManagedObject *facility=array[0];
        if (facility["assessor"]==nil) {
            newAssessor["facility"]=facility;
            // Set up rest of assessor attributes before saving
        } else {
           //  Error - facility already assigned to assessor ?
        }
    } else if (count == 0) {
      //  Code not found/valid - do something
    } else {
       // More than 1 matching facility - data error 
   }
}
else {
    // Deal with error. 
}
```

Comment: This adds the new user and creates the relationship. However, if you have multiple users 'pointing' to the same Facility, it removes the previous relationships (become NULL). So only the last added assessor will have have a relationship with the facility. Do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: I assumed that you wanted a 1-1 relationship between facilities and assessors.  If you want 1-many then you need to store an array of assessors

Comment: I just realised that. Thank you Paul. :)
I just changed the relationship to 1-many and that fixed the problem.